# INSERT has more target columns than expressions

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Не могу добавить значение строку в таблицу пишет:
INSERT has more target columns than expressions

```
with orderset_exists as (
    SELECT 
        status_id
    FROM
        order_status
    WHERE
        order_id=40
        AND order_id_item=0
    ORDER BY
        "time" DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
    INSERT INTO public.order_status(
        order_id,order_id_item,cause,status_id,user_hash,"time")
    SELECT
        (40,0,'',2,'userhash','2017-03-23 13:49')
    FROM orderset_exists WHERE orderset_exists.status_id < 4 RETURNING order_id
```

---

А когда делаю делаю так то все нормально:

```
   INSERT INTO public.order_status(
        order_id,order_id_item,cause,status_id,user_hash,"time")
    VALUES
        (40,0,'',2,'userhash','2017-03-23 13:49')
```

Comment: Стоп, а разве канает " за место \` в колонках, а не их значений?

Comment: Ошибок не выдает по крайне мере) а вот на ` выдает ошибку. Но  я работаю в postgres не знаю вашу бд

Comment: @And это не MySQL, если что.

Comment: А нафига Вы используете INSERT ... SELECT, если у Вас сплошь литералы? Просто чтобы выполнять вставку лишь в случае, когда в orderset_exists будет запись? причём только если status_id < 4...

Comment: Именно так, что бы сделать проверку на последний статус

Comment: Кстати, а вы уверены, что по условию `status_id < 4` вернется 0 или ровно 1 строка ? Если вдруг вернется более одной строки - то несколько одинаковых строк будут вставлены ...

Comment: @Mike `LIMIT 1` же. Всё в порядке.

Comment: @D-side, тогда `sql` надо убрать. Обратил сразу на него внимание.

Comment: @And чего это вдруг? PostgreSQL очень даже относится к SQL :)

Comment: @D-side, относится, но не `SQL`, а `PostgreSQL`. Синтаксисы немного отличаются.

Comment: @And скорее даже наоборот, [синтаксис MySQL отклоняется от стандартного SQL в этом отношении](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901499/2076787).

Comment: @D-side, Ну речь то идет именно о `PostgreSQL` и его работе, так как тс работает именно с ним.

Comment: @And Тогда вопросов с SQL если так смотреть будет всего несколько штук где обсуждается общие теоретические вопросы. А 95% вопросов связаны с той или иной СУБД. И если вопрос не связан с какими то особенностями (например с физической организацией БД) конкретной СУБД то imho лучше указывать оба тега.

Comment: @And проверил, эта же ошибка проявляется и в MySQL, только выводится иначе: `ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`. Вызвана тем же. Исправляется так же. Так что метку [tag:sql] вернул обратно. Почти уверен, что если проверить на других SQL-совместимых СУБД, эффект будет таким же.

Comment: Проверил на SQLite, тоже проявляется, с сухим `Error: near ",": syntax error`.

Comment: Кстати, на свежем постгресе, (9.4, если это не фича клиента, конечно), даже выводится, в чём может быть проблема: `HINT:  The insertion source is a row expression containing the same number of columns expected by the INSERT. Did you accidentally use extra parentheses?` (Для вставки дано выражение-ряд с таким же числом элементов, как ожидалось в INSERT. Вы случайно использовали лишние скобки?)

Comment: Вот портируемый меж SQLite, MySQL и Postgres пример, любой желающий может проверить и убедиться: `CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data VARCHAR(255)); INSERT INTO test (id, data) SELECT ('41', '42');`

Comment: Я не прав был. Я подумал,что это другой синтаксис, все на sql построено. Да уж... бывают иногда сложности =))

Answer (score 3):

В postgresql есть такая вещь как массивы ... Запрос

```
SELECT (40,0,'',2,'userhash','2017-03-23 13:49') ...
```

Возвращает *одну* колонку, содержащую массив из перечисленных значений.

В отличие от него, запрос

```
SELECT 40,0,'',2,'userhash','2017-03-23 13:49' ...
```

вернет 6 колонок, как и задумывалось. Мораль - не используйте скобки, когда они не необходимы.

Answer (score 1):

## Постгрес прав.

У вас действительно для вставки указано колонок больше, чем значений, сильно больше:

```
INSERT INTO public.order_status(
    order_id,order_id_item,cause,status_id,user_hash,"time")
--  1        2             3     4         5         6
SELECT
    (40,0,'',2,'userhash','2017-03-23 13:49')
--  1
FROM orderset_exists
```

Да, вся эта скобочная конструкция это **одно значение**. Скорее всего, круглые скобки лишние.

Comment: может так будет понятнее 
`($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)
    FROM orderset_exists WHERE orderset_exists.status_id < 4 RETURNING order_id`

Comment: @Ghost нет, почему вы селектите в `orderset_exists` что-то помимо `status_id`, если больше ничего не используете -- понятнее не стало.

Comment: А блин это черновой вариант, в рабочем только status_id. Когда все логические соображения у меня закончились я стал делать всякий бред. В рабочем только status_id

Comment: @Ghost а, ок, убрал примечание.